# Show unicity of such ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the unique second order and linear ODE with the property that $z = 0$ and $z = \infty$ are singular regular values of such ODE is the equation:

$$z^2y'' + \alpha z y' + \beta y = 0.$$

I have proved that $0, \infty$ are as wish, but, what is the trick to show that this is the unique equation?

What I am trying is: Let $y'' + p(z)y' + q(z) = 0$ another ODE as searched with the same property. I have to show that $p(z) = \frac{\alpha}{z}$ and $q(z) = \frac{\beta}{z^2}$, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can make the change of variables $x(t) = y(e^z)$, write a differential equation on $x(t)$ (it will be a linear ODE of second order with constant coefficients ) solve it, then colnclude on the unicity of $y$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, thank you!

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, I have to consider $t = e^z?$

Comment: @TZakrevskiy it did not work, do I missing anything?

Comment: Show how you tried to apply this change of variables, otherwise we can't guess why it didn't work for you.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, $x(t) = y(e^z)$ then the equation I get is: $$x'' + x'(\frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{t\log t}) + x\frac{1}{t^2\log^2(t)} = 0.$$

This because:

$$\frac{dx}{dz} = \frac{dy}{dz}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dt}{dz}$$

and so on...

Comment: You consider the change of variables $z=e^t$, and $x(t) = y(e^t)$, which gives 

$$\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = y'(e^t)e^t,\quad \frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(t) = y''(e^t)e^{2t}+y'(e^t)e^t.$$

This results in a differential equation on $x$:
$$x''(t) + (\alpha-1) x'(t)+\beta x(t)=0$$